# not able to get promise from function in node js

Tags: node.js

i am trying to exec command from my node function, but i am not able to get promiss from the function, can anyone please check my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

```
    function exec_api() {
        return new Promise( function(resolve){
            const execSync = require('child_process').exec;
            execSync('DB_HOST='+process.env.NODEJS_UNITTEST_DB_HOST+' DB_DATABASE='+process.env.NODEJS_UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE+'  DB_USERNAME='+process.env.NODEJS_UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME+' DB_PASSWORD='+process.env.NODEJS_UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD+'  PORT='+process.env.NODEJS_UNITTEST_SERVICE_PORT+' sudo nodemon server.js', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.log("sdsdsd23");
                //console.log(`stdout:`+stdout);
                //console.log(`stderr:`+stderr);
                if (err) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {                
                    resolve(true);
                }
            }); 
        });    
    }

it('Exec API', function() {
    this.timeout(3500);
    return exec_api().should.eventually.be.true;
});
```

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: just edited my question added there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a promise you'll have to wait for it to resolve and then you can get the resolved value.

There are two ways, either `return` after it has resolved by making the function `async` like so:

```
it('Exec API', async function() {
    this.timeout(3500);
    const res = await exec_api();
    return res;
});
```

or

use the `then` method on the callback like so:

```
it('Exec API', function() {
    this.timeout(3500);
    let result;
    exec_api().then(res => result = res)
    return result;
});
```

Comment: you're welcome! :D
hahaha I already did but you have another downvote sorry xP

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ShouldJs and mocha, It should be

```
it('Exec API', function() {
    return exec_api().should.be.eventually.equal(true);
});
```